# Why aren't my animated .gif images animated?

Tags: 11.10, browser, gif

**OS Version** : Ubuntu 11.10 x64

**Browser tested** :

Firefox - **Not working**

Nightly - **Not working**

Google Chrome - **Not working**

Midori - **Works**

Currently, i'm using 64 bit version of Ubuntu and i've installed a few web browsers. Almost all of them does not display an animation of the .gif file but instead it freezes like any other static images. However, midori works instead. Is there any fixes ?

Comment: DEBUNKED - privoxy settings are meant to filter out gif's :: FIXED

Comment: Good Job!  Since you fixed it please put it in an answer and how you fixed it then select it as an answer.  It will hope others down the road and show this as complete.

Answer (score 2):

OP fixed the problem, was with privoxy

> privoxy settings are meant to filter out gif's :: FIXED